# ocaml equivalent of php's openssl_verify function

Tags: openssl, ocaml

I'm trying to make an ocaml version of https://github.com/Yubico/php-u2flib-server/blob/master/src/u2flib_server/U2F.php but it seems like I don't understand all of it, I'm trying to finish the doRegister function.

I can successfully decode all the infos, and I end up with a valid pem certificate, what looks like a proper signature and the data to check. I'm looking for the ocaml equivalent of php's openssl_verify (line 231 of the php file), but looking at the doc I'm not sure of what it does exactly.

I'm targeting MirageOS so I can't just use the C library.

Comment: IIRC, there might be some TLS implementation inside MirageOS (so in Ocaml mostly). But I could be wrong (I might have heard that in a talk a year ago). You could ask on some MirageOS mailing list

Comment: Thanks, just sent it to the ML !

Comment: This question is not for SO, so I will vote to close. Such questions should be asked on OCaml Discuss board or Discord channels. There are plenty of cryptographic libraries in OCaml, to name a few:
sha (https://github.com/djs55/ocaml-sha/), digestif (https://github.com/mirage/digestif), cryptokit (https://github.com/xavierleroy/cryptokit)

Comment: I don't understand how this is not an SO question, I'm looking for a way to check a signature in pure ocaml. These libs don't do that, unfortunately, and from the answer I got on the mirage mailing list the problem isn't as simple as using some lib. Looks like nothing implements this, unfortunatly